# gen-class in clojure and use it immediately

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to use `gen-class` to create a class without compiling it? I'm following a tutorial for orbit and am getting stuck here: https://github.com/orbit/orbit/wiki/Getting-Started%3A-Hello-World#actor-implementation.

I can use `gen-interface` to make an interface:

```
(import cloud.orbit.actors.Actor)
(import cloud.orbit.actors.runtime.AbstractActor)
(import cloud.orbit.concurrent.Task)

(gen-interface
 :name example.Hello
 :extends [cloud.orbit.actors.Actor]
 :methods [[sayHello [String] cloud.orbit.concurrent.Task]])
```

but `gen-class` doesn't work and I'm getting stuck

```
(gen-class
 :name example.HelloActor
 :extends [cloud.orbit.actors.runtime.AbstractActor]
 :implements [example.Hello]
 :methods [[sayHello [String] cloud.orbit.concurrent.Task]])
```

Comment: uhh... there's no error. gen-class requires the file to be compiled and I want to use the class straight away

Comment: This implies you must compile first:  https://clojure.org/reference/compilation

Comment: thus the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the repl you could also do:

```
(def original-compile-files *compile-files*)
(alter-var-root #'*compile-files* (constantly true))
(gen-class
 :name example.HelloActor
 :extends [cloud.orbit.actors.runtime.AbstractActor]
 :implements [example.Hello]
 :methods [[sayHello [String] cloud.orbit.concurrent.Task]])
(alter-var-root #'*compile-files* (constantly original-compile-files))
```

Then the `example.HelloActor` class should be available on the repl classpath immediately.

This has implications of course in that you have to alter the var root, which is not ideal. In this example I just set it back to its default of `false` when done.

Comment: second constantly true should be constantly false?

Comment: @pete23 that is better yes. I think ideally, it would be restored to whatever it was previously. However, if nothing else was done previously, the default is indeed false. I can update it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this flowchart?

https://github.com/cemerick/clojure-type-selection-flowchart

[image]

I don't have much experience with `gen-class`, `proxy`, et al, but you should be sure to review all of the options under "Proxy" [on the Clojure Cheatsheet.](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure you should sound like an authority on this if you don't have the experience. The reason why proxy doesn't work is because it constructs an actual instance, not a Class template which is need by the orbit actor framework.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, you cannot use `gen-class` without compiling.

The more interesting answer is: yes, you can use `gen-class` from the repl **if** your repl has the right settings.

Here is a working example for Boot: https://gist.github.com/jeroenvandijk/8187413d24433545eeb9579538a903f7#file-repl_compile-clj-L39-L52

Comment: Please refer [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Though this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: I haven't been able to undefine a loaded class yet.. So redefine classes is an issue. You have to use new names to make it work otherwise. I played a bit with a custom ClassLoader but no luck.